# Combine meshes imported at run time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime, mesh

Meshes in Unity max at 65k vertices. I'm importing high level of detail (fancy way to say high quality) models at run-time that pass this limit. Because of this, I often have to create multiple meshes for a single model. Each of these meshes is put in its own Game Object (Unity allows only one mesh on a given Game Object). I then parent all of these separate GameObjects into an single empty parent Game Object.

What I would like to be able to do is interact with all of the meshes as if they were under a single Mesh Collider. Is this possible?

My current research has turned up the following: [link 1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10249/combining-meshes-with-submeshes.html) and [link 2](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/492819/mesh-collider-with-multiple-meshes.html).

Link one doesn't seem to be really what I am after, and link two, did not work the way I am wanting it to when I tried it with a manual import. It created the meshes the same way AddComponent does, but it created the colliders for each mesh individually.

Rather, I want it to create a single unified Mesh Collider for all of the meshes needed to represent an individual model.

Pipe dream or possible?

Comment: My guess would be that this won't be possible. I suggest creating a low-poly version of the model to use as a collider. Additionally, mesh colliders are computationally expensive to calculate and if the object moves, rotates, or scales during runtime, Unity needs to recalculate the mesh collider.

Comment: Creating low poly versions might be the best solution.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm utilizing [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/228841/dynamically-combine-verticies-that-share-the-same.html?childToView=1371775#comment-1371775) mesh "welding" code, but I'm having trouble determining what threshold and bucketStep do exactly

Comment: `threshold` is how close two verts need to be to get welded. `bucketsize` appears to be just a cubic segmentation of the object to aid processing. I have never used it, so I have no idea.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm actively trying to use this function but it doesn't make much sense. For example, if I've both threshold and bucketStep = .03, I can reduce a 12k vertice mesh to 1.7k vertices. If I increase bucketStep to .04, the reduced result is now 1.4k vertices. But, if I decrement bucketStep to .01, the reduced result is 1.7k. So you can see my confusion as changing the value in both directions doesn't seem to make much sense

Comment: Like I said, I have no idea what that value actually does. It appears to break the model down into regions (if you think about a rubik's cube that is 3 meters long, then a bucketStep of 1 breaks that cube down into 27 1x1 regions, right along the breaks in the plastic). But as for how changing that value affects the outcome? No idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [Mesh.CombineMeshes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html) :

```
public void CombineMeshes(CombineInstance[] combine, bool mergeSubMeshes = true, bool useMatrices = true, bool hasLightmapData = false);
```

> Combines several Meshes into this Mesh.

From the documentation:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < meshFilters.Length) {
            combine[i].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
            combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            meshFilters[i].gameObject.active = false;
            i++;
        }
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = new Mesh();
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
        transform.gameObject.active = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mesh.CombineMeshes still has a hard limit of 65,000 vertices.